# Chrome Extension (Manifest v3) call Google Apps Script deployed as WebApp with OAuth2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension

I have CORS Error when I fetch apps script with OAuth2 from Chrome Extension

Configuration:

- There is a Google Apps Script project deployed as Web App, access is limited to **only domain user**

Code as below:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  };
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"code": 200, "data": "aaaa"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  output.setHeaders(headers);
  return output;
}
```

Chrome Extension, manifest v3:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "DEMO",
    "version": "1.0.0.3",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "identity", "identity.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.webapp.deploy", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["jquery-3.6.0.min.js", "content.js"],
        "all_frames": false
      }
    ],
    "oauth2": {
      "client_id": "<PERSONAL_ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.webapp.deploy"]
    },
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
          "16": "assets/alembic.png",
          "24": "assets/alembic.png",
          "32": "assets/alembic.png",
          "128": "assets/alembic.png"
        },
        "default_title": "DEMO",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }
```

And the background.js, the function `call_appscript()` is called when `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is triggered

```
function call_appsscript() {

    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function(token) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          return;
        }
      
        // Fetch the URL of the web app
        const url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/<DOMAIN>/s/<DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec"
        const headers = new Headers({
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        });
        const init = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: headers,
        };
        fetch(url, init).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });

}
```

Credentials are well configured (tutorial with manifest v2: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/tut_oauth/)`

Error :
`chrome-extension://xxx has been blocked by CORS policy`

Another reference which did not help : [How do i allow a CORS requests in my google script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433938/how-do-i-allow-a-cors-requests-in-my-google-script)

Comment: Note: CORS error seems to be the default behaviour. There is not log activities from the apps script project, I suppose identification is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"code": 200, "data": "aaaa"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return output;
}
```

#### Javascript side:

##### From:

```js
const url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/<DOMAIN>/s/<DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec"
const headers = new Headers({
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
});
const init = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers,
};
fetch(url, init).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

##### To:

```js
const token = "###"; // Please set your access token.

const url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/<DOMAIN>/s/<DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec?access_token=" + token;
fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

- By this modification, the following value is obtained in the log.

  ```
    {"code": 200, "data": "aaaa"}
  ```

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that you have already had permission for accessing Web Apps. Please be careful about this.
- In the case of a request to Web Apps, please include the scope of Drive API in your access token.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Sorry Tanaike, but I'm facing troubles when executing from different account (same domain). It seems the Fetch is only working from my session. Maybe I have some permissions that new account doesn't have. Could you give me more details about ```it supposes that you have already had permission for accessing Web Apps``` Sorry to bother you, if this is different problem, tell me and I will post a new question

Comment: @Waxim Corp About your comment, I would like to check your new question.